# Editing When You were not signed in

Tags: support, edits

I've edited a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9988370) while I was not signed in. In the review page it says that an anonymous user edited this question. Is there anyway to add my name to this edit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to reject the edit with a custom reason to make clear why it was rejected.

This will spare precious developer time from the SE team, which would else need to reassociate a single suggested edit to your account.

A little strange to do it like this, but it is the cleanest way to do this fast. And hey, it is meta after all.

Comment: If the edit would have been accepted [this route](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) should have been followed.

Comment: The dev team could save time by simply associating every single anonymous edit with the above account.  Efficiency!

Comment: @Yakk yeah cuz that would never be abused with incognito mode.